# FancyTree: How do I Expand all nested/subsequent nodes? Not only current nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, fancytree

When I use the following Fancytree even action:

```
$(document).on('click', '.expand-all', function () {
                $.ui.fancytree.getTree().expandAll();
            });
```

[image]

Fancytree only expands current nodes but not more level sub/nested nodes. Suppose following doesn't happen same time:

[image]

How do I achieve that on single event?

Comment: can you make this runnable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out it and done this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.expand-all-nested', function (e) {
            expandNodes();

            function expandNodes() {
                $.ui.fancytree.getTree("#treegrid").visit(function (node) {
                    if (node.isLazy() && !node.isExpanded() && !node.isLoading()) {
                        node.setExpanded(true).done(() => {
                                console.log('Auto Expanding Children');
                                expandNodes()
                            }
                        ).catch(function (error) {
                            //Error occurred. Trying re-fetching data
                            console.log('Error occurred. Trying re-fetching data');
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                node.load(true).done(() => {
                                    console.log('Successfully Re-fetched errored data');
                                }).catch(function () {
                                    console.log('Couldn\'t Re-fetch errored data');
                                });
                            }, 700);
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```